# Change Value of DATA attribute on jQuery Inserted HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm adding elements to my page using jquery.  The resulting markup looks like:

```
<button id="button-[X]" data-link="some value">Go [X]</button>
```

Where X is a counter, so I get the following inserted:

```
<button id="button-2" data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Go 2</button>
<button id="button-3" data-link="http://www.google.com">Go 3</button>
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I try to change the data value with:

```
$('#button-3').data('link','http://www.stackoverflow');
```

The value isn't changed.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the element exists when you are trying to change the data attribute? Nothing in your code suggests what you have wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you looking at the source to see if that changed? If so, it doesn't when you use `.data()`.

Comment: `.data()` isn't changed on the html of the page, only `.attr()` can do that. once you change it, try getting the value by doing `$('#button-3').data('link');` and you'l see what im talking about.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification. -- taken from http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Why can't you use `$('#button-3').attr('data-link','http://www.stackoverflow');` instead?